# Is there an online JSON resource with Wordpress release informations?

Tags: json, wordpress, release

The CMS TYPO3 has a online resource in JSON format, which contains all versions of the CMS. This is ideal for parsing, and checking active installations if there would be a newer version.

This is the link: [get.typo3.org/json](http://get.typo3.org/json)

My question: Is there anything similar for "Wordpress"?

Thanks

Comment: You can get an RSS feed if thats any good? https://wordpress.org/news/category/releases/feed/

Comment: Thanks. But I does not hold all Wordpress version, only the last 10 entries. Also I would need to parse the file using regular expressions to get the current version number. Not really comparable with the TYPO3 Json version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this resource, returning a JSON string:
[Wordpress Version Checker](https://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.7/)